How to protect a motherboard from an old power supply?
I have an old Taiwanese Senstron ST-41 (TAO YIN-TCY6 94V) power supply from 1987 used in an Apple 2 clone with DC outputs:

5V 5A
12V 2.5A
-5V 0.5A
-12V 0.5A

Is it possible to add extra protection (for the motherboard) on the outputs caused by a critical problem in the power supply? I would like to put fuses in each output line, but it seems that might not work well.


What type of error would you like to protect from?

Failed capacitor, transformer or other elements. Or maybe borrow some kind of PSU protection from modern power supplies and transplant it on this one.

On which side do you think will the mentioned elements fail, motherboard or supply? Most such failures don't lead to excessive current, but this is all what blows a fuse.

The most practical thing to do may be to replace the entire power supply with a modern one, assuming something with the right ampacity for each rail can be found.

A fuse at the output of a power supply, protects it from damage that could be caused by over-current or short-circuit. It definitely cannot protect the load (motherboard in this case).
'Crowbar protection' would be required to prevent damage to the motherboard in the case of over voltage.

Use one of the TVS Diodes across each rail. Once it turns on, it will clamp the voltage or die trying. Select one large enough, like 5KVA, to blow up any PSU. It costs a buck or two on Mouser.

